# IntelliJ Code Coverage: how to know which unit tests covered lines in source code

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

I'm pretty new to this awesome feature of IntelliJ. When I run code coverage, I can see in the IDE green marks that indicate whether the line was covered and red marks that indicate
whether this line was not covered. It's great. But I want to see what were the unit tests that covered these lines.

When I click the green marks, I only see number of hits:

[image]

Do you know how to see it?

Comment: I know that [OpenClover](https://openclover.org/) has such a feature, but I have no clue if there is IntelliJ integration that would show this.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I tried it now. It is really heavy and increases the loading time of Intellij.

Answer (score 7):

At first you need to enable the "Tracing" in Run configuration:
[image]

Then you may use "Show tests covering line" button:
[image]

Comment: In my case the option is called "Enable branch coverage and test tracking" (using 2023.2)